# download generated zip with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, storage, laravel-filesystem

I´m trying dowload zip with my files in my app laravel. To build this logic, i´m using,`ZipArchive` and i including all my files in foreach. Zip it´s generated ok, and files it´s included. But browser not download this file. I´m trying dowload with this code:

```
response()->download($zipPath, 'contratos_seleccionados.zip', $headers);
return response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
```

My zip, it´s saved in my folder. But i need to do that user can view this file it´s download. like when we download on google.

All my logic it´s:

```
$path = public_path('/storage/contracts/bills/');

                if(!File::isDirectory($path)){
                    File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
                }
                
                $fileName =  'contrato_'.$ids.'.pdf';
                $pdf->save($path . '/' . $fileName);
                $result = $pdf->download($fileName);

                $zip = new ZipArchive;
                $zipFileName = 'contratos_seleccionados.zip';
                $zipPath = public_path('/storage/contracts/'.$zipFileName);

                if ($zip->open($zipPath, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
                    $filesToZip = [
                        $path . '/' . $fileName,
                    ];

                    foreach ($filesToZip as $file) {
                        $zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
                    }

                    $zip->close();

                    if (file_exists($zipPath)) {

                        $result = response()->download($zipPath);
                        if($result){
                            //\Storage::download($zipPath, $zipFileName);
                            //\Storage::download($zipPath, "prueba.zip");
                            //\Storage::disk('contracts')->download($zipFileName);
                            $headers = [
                                'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
                             ];
                  
                            response()->download($zipPath, 'contratos_seleccionados.zip', $headers);
                            return response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
                        }
                    }
```

I tryed with comment code, and any way with `response()->download` but never show in browser file downloading.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Try with `storage_path` on this line `$zipPath = public_path('/storage/contracts/'.$zipFileName);`

Comment: @KamranAllana thanks for your response, but same problem

Comment: Have you checked the path is correct?

Comment: Are you zipping single file right?

Comment: @KamranAllana yes, now i´m zipping only file. My route it´s correct. My file it´s in ```app/public/storage/contracts```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($result) {
  $headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
  ];

  response()->download(storage_path('app/public/contracts/'.$zipFileName), 'contratos_seleccionados.zip', $headers);
  return response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help and comments, but not run. route in storage path it´s: ```response()->download(storage_path('app/public/contracts/'.$zipFileName), 'contratos_seleccionados.zip', $headers);``` file it´s saved in this route, but browser not download it

Comment: Would you please check this route through `dd(storage_path('app/public/contracts/'.$zipFileName)`, is it correct?

Comment: As I've done this before and working fine without any headers.

Comment: put `return  response()->download(storage_path('app/public/storage/contracts/'.$zipFileName), 'contratos_seleccionados.zip', $headers);` and check.

Comment: in dd i have ```C:\xampp\htdocs\gds_nuevo\storage\app/public/contracts/contratos_seleccionados.zip```

With ```return  response()->download(storage_path('app/public/storage/contracts/'.$zipFileName), 'contratos_seleccionados.zip', $headers);``` return ```"C:\xampp\htdocs\gds_nuevo\storage\app/public/storage/contracts/contratos_seleccionados.zip" does not exist```

Comment: I've edited answer try with this.

Comment: same problem, i don´t know that it´s happening

Comment: with this line: ```return response()->download($zipPath, 'contratos_seleccionados.zip', $headers);``` in tab network in webrowser return: ```Ђ�W鉡[��``` for example, but not download pdf, but it´s in folder i don´t understand

Comment: I try to return path one more time, and return ```C:\xampp\htdocs\gds_nuevo\public\/storage/contracts/contratos_seleccionados.zip``` if i put this url in browser, my file it´s downloaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256249/discussion-between-kamran-allana-and-scorpions77).